# Android call a .net webservice that needs to communicate with Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, android, queue, addition, android-webservice

i'll try to explain you my problem.

I have to call a .net webservice with my android device.

But, this `webservice` needs to add items on a queue on an another service who's running on my server.

**Android ---> .net WebService ---> add items on queue on another Windows Form Application.**

In brief I want my application to communicate with my Windows Form Application **without using database**

Do you think this is possible? 
If it's possible have you any idea how do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use socket to communicate with your server application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx